# How to override the default BackKey button when page created

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Here the default backKey button when a page is created:

The problem:

How to override this ? I want to check something before this backKey canGoBack !

```
 <Button Content="Button" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="16,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55"/>


---- Update : in LayoutAwarePage.cs


protected virtual void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Use the navigation frame to return to the previous page
            if (this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack) this.Frame.GoBack();
        }
```

Comment: Is it for Windows Phone 8 or Windows 8 ?

Comment: For Windows 8, sorry for the wrong tag used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

```
protected override void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.GoBack(sender, e);
    //Your logic goes here
}
```

---

I think you are using `LayoutAwarePage` class. It has implementation of `GoBack` event. You can edit the implementation. LayoutAwarePage.cs will be in common folder of project.

Comment: If I edit GoBack in LayoutAwarePage.cs, will this apply to all my pages? I dont want this happen. I want to override for the current page.

Comment: Yes it will be affect to all pages. If you want to apply to specific page you can override the event.